# Illegal mix of collations MySQL Error in Query laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm getting this error when I try this query

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1270 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT), (latin1_bin,NONE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'
```

Here my query

```
     $codigoRadicado = DB::table('radicado')
    ->leftJoin ('dependencia','radicado.Dependencia_idDependencia', "=", 'dependencia.idDependencia')
    ->leftJoin ('serie','radicado.Serie_idSerie', "=", 'serie.idSerie')
    ->leftJoin ('subserie','radicado.SubSerie_idSubSerie', "=", 'subserie.idSubSerie')     
    ->select (DB::raw("CONCAT(abreviaturaDependencia, codigoSerie, codigoSubSerie,LPAD((MAX(REPLACE ( codigoRadicado , CONCAT(abreviaturaDependencia, codigoSerie, codigoSubSerie), '' ))+1),10,'0')) as codigoRadicado"))
    ->where ('radicado.Dependencia_idDependencia', "=", $request['Dependencia_idDependencia'])
    ->where ('radicado.Serie_idSerie', "=", $request['Serie_idSerie'])
    ->where ('radicado.SubSerie_idSubSerie', "=", $request['SubSerie_idSubSerie'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: check your tables' schemas

Comment: Hi,

this isn't not a error of laravel. You should to change the collation tables to prevent the error.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is throwing the error when the SQL statement is being executed. The error message indicates the issue is occurring in a 'replace' operation.

That seems to point to the REPLACE() function as the likely culprit.

```
REPLACE( codigoRadicado , CONCAT(abreviaturaDependencia,codigoSerie,codigoSubSerie) , '' )
```

And that seems to line up with the error message, indicating a difference in charactersets/collations

```
(latin1_spanish_ci,IMPLICIT), (latin1_bin,NONE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE)
```

We're not sure, but we suspect the order of the collations is the same as the order of the arguments to the REPLACE function.

But the error is indicating that we have a "mix" of collations, and MySQL isn't going to violate it's "coercibility" rules.

The typical fix for this type of problem is to identify the collation of each expression, and then wrap one (or more) of the expressions in an explicit conversion.    CONVERT(foo USING collation)

For string literals, we can take a shortcut and specify the characterset (which gets a default collation) e.g.   _latin1'foo'

To get the characterset and collation of each column used in the expression, you can check the table definition.  The output of SHOW CREATE TABLE should show you that. (If it's not specified on the column, then its the default that was assigned when the table was created.  (If that wasn't specified when the table was created, it defaulted to the value assigned to the database.)

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-expressions.html

Each characterset has a default collation. We can find the default collation for each characterset with a query...

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.charactersets
```

And we can get a complete list of collations for another query...

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.collations
```

MySQL also provides a COERCIBILITY function that can be of help in debugging the issue, to help us figure out which column or literal expression can't be "coerced" into a different collation.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_coercibility

(I'm not sure that any of that answered the question you asked, because I'm not sure there was an actual *question*. I'm just guessing that you intended to ask a question e.g. "Why is this error being thrown?", and you weren't just posting a status report.)